# How to find whether SQL server report services and BIDS is installed?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, powershell, registry, prerequisites

Our installation should work both on SQL 2008 R2 and SQL 2012 and the prerequisite is

> SQL server report services and BIDS ( in 2012 SQL Server Data Tools)
>   should be installed before initiating installation.

We needed it via registry keys or file folders (if it creates some folders on installation). But even if BIDS is not installed still registry key exists, how to find whether the feature is installed or not.

Even if a powershell script to verify this , it will be helpful.

Comment: can this be done without using the registry? or is using the registry part of the requirement?

Comment: @D3vtr0n: If any project template is created in some folder , i can check whether that folder exist or not. By this way also i can ensure. does it have any thing like that?